# In what way is the game different (or the same) when you play in 'Hero Mode'?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

So the game actually has a `Hero Mode` which is unlocked when you beat the game.

What are the changes that I can expect when playing in `Hero Mode`?  What remains?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's the changes that I was told by characters in the game or have observed so far:

- The slot in the quest selection screen will have the goddess insignia on it.
- You can **Skip** almost all cinematic and dialog sequences
- Keep all bugs and treasures from previous adventure
- Some characters will acknowledge that you're playing in **Hero Mode** as they speak with you**
  *What they say to you will change telling you what has changed or allowing you to skip some explanations.*
- You lose hearts twice as fast as you normally do
- All hints are unlocked at **Sheikah Stones**
- Maximum strength **Skyward Strike** always
  *Every **Skyward Strike** you perform will have the strength as if you had used the **Master Sword**, including the faster charge.  After getting the actual **Master Sword**, charging is instantaneous.*
- **Hearts** and **Heart Flowers** no longer appear normally in the game*
  *Monsters, pots and other sources do not drop hearts anymore.  You will have to heal by using potions, fairies, sleeping or sitting in chairs.  *Equipping the **Heart Medal** will provide a reduced chance for **Hearts** and **Heart Flowers** of appearing.*
- **Fi** will remember how many of each type of monster you defeated from your previous adventure
  *When **Fi** analyzes a targeted enemy, the count will continue from where you left off.*
- Your high score at **Bamboo Island** and *other places* that keep records will remain from the previous adventure
- The **Boss Rush** challenge now includes the game's final battle, in addition to the other eleven battles you could access in regular mode.  You must have defeated the boss at least once before they are playable.

> - Beating the game this time around will allow you to save just before the final battle and you get a Triforce icon in the quest selection screen.

To all hardcore Zelda fans out there, the game is *a lot* more challenging in this mode so it's definitely worth it to play through.

Comment: You can skip cinematics the first time around too by pushing <kbd>②</kbd>.

Comment: Are you sure about that @CyberSkull?  The first time around, I am pretty sure you _must_ wait through it all.

Comment: The game seems to log cut scenes. I went and reset after a scene, and when I did it again the <kbd>②</kbd> prompt appeared with "Skip" next to it.

Comment: If you die and have to watch a cut scene again you can skip it, I know. Not sure about otherwise.

Comment: Ok so you have to see it at least once before you can skip. I never died on my first run so I wouldn't have known. :)

Comment: The Boss Rush mode has the final Ghirahim battle, the final Imprisoned battle, and the Sealed Grounds descent battle, *even in the first playthrough*, at any point after you've beaten them in the story. Likewise, you can do the Skyloft Silent Realm during the first playthrough as well.

So the only difference in the Thunder Dragon games in Hero Mode is that it has the Demise battle. I've submitted an edit to that effect.

Comment: @75thTrombone: Really?  I'll have to accept your edit then